# GitLab shell install rake failing

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, gitlab

I'm not a ruby developer so it is very hard for me to understand this language... But I get this error when trying to run rake install on gitlab. I am using postgresql and I followed the guide on how to install. All of the gems installed without an issue.

```
 root@gitlab-server:/home/git/gitlab# cd /home/git/gitlab && sudo -u git -H bune exec rake gitlab:shell:install REDIS_URL=unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock RAILS_ENV=production --trace
 ** Invoke gitlab:shell:install (first_time)
 ** Invoke environment (first_time)
 ** Execute environment
 rake aborted!
 NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "\\#":String
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
 /home/git/gitlab/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
 /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
 Tasks: TOP => gitlab:shell:install => environment
```

Comment: Do you have this `\\#` string defined anywhere in your config files? Seems that ruby expects an array or hash in place of this string.

Comment: Perhaps you tried using `\\` to designate a comment as opposed to `#` ?

Answer (score 0):

somewhere you called `each` method onto String type.